# autotools and python setup.py

Tags: python, autotools

I have a project written mostly in c++ that includes a few helper scripts written in python. For the moment, the scripts contain variables substituted by the autotools:

```
#!@PYTHON@
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...

try:
    datapath = os.environ['DATA_PATH']
except KeyError:
    datapath = '@pkgdatadir@'
```

And here is an extract of Makefile.am:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = script.py
nodist_python_PYTHON = script.py 
CLEANFILES = $(python_PYTHON)
EXTRA_DIST = script.py.in 

do_subst = sed -e 's,[@]PYTHON[@],$(PYTHON),g'\
           -e 's,[@]pkgdatadir[@],$(pkgdatadir),g'

script.py: script.py.in
    $(do_subst) < $< > $@
chmod +x $@
```

These scripts have also a few module dependencies which would probably be better handled by a setup.py script.

So what is the best way to mix the autotools and the python distutils tools? Should I rely entirely on the autotools? Otherwise how can I integrate the launching of setup.py in the Makefile.am?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use autoconf to setup script.py instead of 'make' as you've shown. Something like:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([script.py], [chmod +x script.py])
```

before AC_OUTPUT in configure.ac should do it.

Comment: Good point, this will do the substitution automatically. However, it doesn't really help with python dependencies.

Comment: I'm just reading in the doc that directory variable are not fully expanded by AC_CONFIG_FILES, so this would not work well for $(pkgdatadir).

Comment: I was wrong. My answer will not work with pkgdatadir because it get setup at install time.

Comment: autoconf advises against such replacements through configure:
"you should not rely on AC_CONFIG_FILES to replace bindir and friends in your shell scripts and other files", see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Installation-Directory-Variables.html#Installation-Directory-Variables